# Why the content of some cells is modified following knitting of a kable object?

Tags: knitr, kableextra

I have started today working with kableExtra to create tables in R markdown.
I am satisfied with the output of the script when run.
However, following knitting the value that are in the (00) format representing percentages are unexpectedly changed to 00. with a change in alignment.
Is there a. way to correct this, please?

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 0))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(X1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
         X2 = c("n (%)", "n (%)", "median (IQR)", "median (IQR)", "n (%)"),
         X3 = c(5,6,2,4,5), 
         x4 = c("(15)", "(23)", "(1-3)", "(2-5)", "(15)"))

kable(df, col.names = c("", "", "", ""), align = c("l", "l", "r", "l")) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Number of cases" = 2, "60" = 2), line = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Admission" = 2), line = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Table 1." = 4), align = "left") %>%
  column_spec(c(3:4), width = "3em") %>%
  column_spec(c(2), width = "7em") %>%
  column_spec(c(1), width = "6em") %>%
  footnote(general = "IQR, interquantile range")
```

[image: Table after run]

[image: Table after knit]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue only when within the brackets there is an integer number. Adding a decimal digit to the percentages solved the problem.

I have used `sprintf` to force the maintenance of a single digit (even when .0) in my actual code with `round_half_up`.

Here is the reproducible code instead.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 0))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(X1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
         X2 = c("n (%)", "n (%)", "median (IQR)", "median (IQR)", "n (%)"),
         X3 = c(5,6,2,4,5), 
         x4 = c("(15.8)", "(23)", "(1-3)", "(2-5)", "(15.0)"))

kable(df, col.names = c("", "", "", ""), align = c("l", "l", "r", "l")) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "condensed", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Number of cases" = 2, "60" = 2), line = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "Admission" = 2), line = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Table 1." = 4), align = "left") %>%
  column_spec(c(3:4), width = "3em") %>%
  column_spec(c(2), width = "7em") %>%
  column_spec(c(1), width = "6em") %>%
  footnote(general = "IQR, interquantile range")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh0yf.png)